# How do I set the report language in Report Builder 3.0?

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I'm using Report Builder 3.0 to create some reports for an application.  I'm using Report Builder because I'd like the client to be able to customize the reports as needed in the future.  Now, when I edit a report in Visual Studio (that is using Business Intelligence Development Studio), I can set the properties for the report.  That way I can set the language for the report which is important to ensure that all the number/date formats appear correctly, as my client is in France, and they're fussy about that sort of thing.  Setting the language adds an element to the report xml as follows:

```
  </ReportParameters>
  <Language>=User!Language</Language>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Mm</rd:ReportUnitType>
  <rd:ReportServerUrl>http://localhost/reportserver_sql2008r2</rd:ReportServerUrl>
  <rd:ReportID>24c58c7f-2a6a-4f68-878d-d26d97bb16e8</rd:ReportID>
</Report>
```

How can I access the report properties, and specifically the report language in Report Builder?

Thanks,

Patrick Collins

Answer (score 3):

I know this is way old, but it's a valid question.  I've verified that you can do this in Report Builder 2.0 (10.0.4.4000.0) and Report Builder 3.0 (11.0.2100.60):

- Go to the "View" tab of the ribbon at the top of the screen.
- Check the box next to "Properties" - voila, the familiar Properties Pane appears.
- Go to Localization - Language and use the dropdown to select your desired language